# How to convert code form to obtain the above array

Tags: php, sqlite

this is my code:

```
for ($g=1; $g<=$godziny; $g++)
{
    echo '<td style="text-align:center; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; width:'.(90/$godziny).'%;"><span class="text_19">'.((strlen($g) == 1) ? '0'.$g : $g).'</span></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
$numrows = 0;
$result = db_query($dba, "select * from ed_frekwencja where id_ucznia='$id_ucznia' and status='ok' order by data_d, id asc");
while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="frekwencja_id[]" value="'.$row['id'].'">';

    $arrf = explode('|', $row['frekwencja']); 
    echo '<tr class="onclickclass" style="text-align:center;">';
    echo '<td style="text-align:center; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;"><span class="text_26">'.$row['data_d'].'</span></td>';
    for ($i=1; $i<=(empty($godziny) ? 1 : $godziny); $i++) 
    {
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<select class="inputsb" name="frekwencja[]" style="width:45px;">';
        $kol = array('', 'x', 'y', 'z'); // array danych
        foreach($kol as $value) 
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value == $arrf[$i-1]) ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$value.'</option>'; 
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $numrows++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

I currently have such a character array:

```
    Array
(
    [frekwencja_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [frekwencja] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
            [3] => x
            [4] => y
            [5] => z
            [6] => x
            [7] => y
            [8] => z
            [9] => x
            [10] => y
            [11] => z
        )
)
```

and the need to get:

```
 Array
(
    [frekwencja_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )
    [frekwencja_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
    [frekwencja_5] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
    [frekwencja_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
    [frekwencja_4] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

what and where you need to change in order to achieve the above table?

Comment: Your question is not understandable, please update it and add more details what you are going to achieve, otherwise it's to hard do figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello just replace your select with this

```
echo '<select class="inputsb" name="frekwencja['.$i.'][]" style="width:45px;">';
```

and you should get what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Change line 20. You must include the row id in the select name.

...

```
  echo '<select class="inputsb" name="frekwencja_'.$row['id'].'[]" style="width:45px;">';
```

...

This should produce desired results. But as a side note, you have sql injection vulnerabilities in your code.You should never interpolate variables to sql strings directly. You should look into PDO for prepared statements. And also it might be a good idea to use some kind of templating in your projects. You shouldn't mix php with html.